# Is it possible to get credentials of a user who copied a file to a network share?

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher, windows-server, network-share

I have a network share watched by a `FileSystemWatcher` object...

If multiple users on a windows domain have access to copy files to this share, is it possible, using the `FileSystemWatcher` object, or otherwise, to get credentials of a person who copied the file to this network share and how?

Comment: did you already try to sniff the LastWrite username of the file once you detect a new file is there in the network share?

Comment: @DavidePiras Are you referring to FileInfo object of the file? If so, there is no LastWrite property or method on that class... if not, what exactly is LastWrite you are referring to?

Comment: you are right, there is not such property, my mistake sorry! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `FileInfo.GetAccessControl` method to get `FileSecurity` object. Using `GetOwner` method of that `FileSecurity` object you can get the `Principal.NTAccount` object to get the NT user...

```
var fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
var ac = fi.GetAccessControl();
var owner = ac.GetOwner(typeof (System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).Value;
```